# Laplace Transform: Continuous analogue of Power series

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform, riemann-sum

Laplace transform is considered as the continuous analogue of the power series, $$A(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a(n)x^n \rightarrow A(x)= \int_0^\infty a(t)x^t\mathbf {dt} $$ sub $\,\,  x^t=e^{(\ln\,x)^t} $  As the integral converges when $0<x<1,\,\, ln \, x <0$ and hence we consider $\mathbf -s=\ln \, x$
$$\Rightarrow  A(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a(n)x^n \rightarrow A(s)= \int_0^\infty a(t)e^{-st}\mathbf {dt}$$

My question is; How did $\,\,\mathbf {dt}\,\,$ kick in? When we consider a sum, $F(x)=\sum_{n=0}^t f(x)\Delta x $ , limit of this sum as $\Delta x \rightarrow 0 \,\,and \,\,t\rightarrow \infty$ is equal to $F(x)=\int_{n=0}^\infty f(x) \mathbf {dx}\, $. Here, the $\mathbf {\Delta x}$ changed to $\mathbf {dx}$, during the limiting process. But then while considering the continuous analogue of power series of did $\mathbf {dt}$ come in. This question would be naive, but then I'm new to calculus.

Comment: Well, you are looking to include values of $a$ over the continuum so you can look at $\sum_n a(hn) e^{-shn}$. This sum scales like $1/h$ for small $h$ so you multiply by $h$ to scale it down to obtain convergence. So the series you get is in powers of $e^{-sh}$ and the coefficients are $ha(hn)$. This $h$ corresponds to $dt$ in the limit.

Comment: In the end this analogy is not perfect, though.

Comment: @Ian Woah, that explanation is close I suppose, can you explain it a bit more in rookie terms :)

Comment: @Ian Can you please tell me, in what way?

Comment: Mainly that in power series the coefficients are proportional to derivatives; when you replace them by a continuously varying quantity, that interpretation is essentially lost.

Comment: Wow, yeah, can you please explain that $h$ part, I couldn't get that, maybe with a small example please.

Comment: Also $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n e^{-sn}$ is a power series in $e^{-s}$. With $e^{-sn} = s \int_n^\infty e^{-st}dt$ you obtain $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n e^{-sn} = s \int_0^\infty \alpha(t) e^{-st}dt$ where $\alpha(t) = \sum_{n=0}^t a_n$. And $\int_0^\infty \alpha(t) e^{-st}dt$ comes from such a power series iff $\alpha(t)$ is constant on each interval $(n,n+1)$.

Comment: @reuns Sorry man, I really don't get it, what's happening from the second line; With $e^{-s}= ...$

Comment: @Ian Can you **please** write an answer consolidating all you said ?

Comment: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n e^{-sn} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_ns \int_0^\infty 1_{t \ge n} e^{-st}dt =s \int_0^\infty \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n1_{t \ge n} e^{-st}dt $

Comment: @reuns Why is $e^{-sn} = s\, \int_n^\infty e^{-st}\,dt$ Can you please sum it up as an answer?

Comment: You are supposed to know how to differentiate and integrate $g(t)=e^{-st}$

Comment: @reuns yeah okay, finally got that, but please bare with me,  what do you conclude? What does $\alpha(t)$ is constant in $(n,n+1)$ imply

Comment: There is one way to look at it based on the correspondence between the series and the Laplace transform of a function which is constant between each adjacent pair of nonnegative integers. This way you don't need an $h$ to be present because you can just change variables to remove it anyway. If you now want to include a continuum of values of $a$, then you need a different approach, which is what I was suggesting. In this approach, you discretize by looking at $\{ hn : n=0,1,\dots \}$ and sum up $\sum_n a(hn) e^{-shn}$ (so that $a(hn)$ is multiplied with $x^{hn}$, not just $x^n$).

Comment: Now it turns out that this sum will usually blow up as $h \to 0$, essentially because there are $O(1/h)$ terms which are of order $1$ in the sum. One can remove this blowup by multiplying by $h$. In terms of a Riemann sum, this $h$ serves as the $\Delta t$ that will be identified with $dt$ in the limit.

Answer (score 0):

Well I know this reply is pretty late, but

$$A(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a(n)x^n$$ could be written as  $$A(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a(n)x^n \Delta n.$$

Note that $\Delta n$ in this case equals $1$ (the discrete case).