# Inner Product of two functions

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, integration, inner-products

The inner product of two vectors $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ of n dimensions, is given by,
$$(\vec a \,, \vec{b}) =a_1b_1 + a_2b_2 + a_3b_3 + \,\,...\,\,+a_nb_n   $$

If a function is considered to be a vector of infinite dimensions, for example,
$$f(x) = \begin{bmatrix} \vdots \\ f(0.05) \\ f(0.051) \\ f(0.052) \\ \vdots \end{bmatrix}$$
Then, the inner product of two functions say $f(x), g(x)$ is given by $$\mathbf {\bigl(} f(x),g(x)\mathbf {\bigr)}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)g(x) \,\,\, \mathbf{dx}$$
**My Question is:**

How did we get the $\mathbf {dx}$ in the inner product (or)$$ \mathbf{why\,\, is}\,\,\,\,\ \sum_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)g(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)g(x) \,\,\, \mathbf{dx}$$
In a Riemann sum , the $\Delta x $ term becomes $dx$ during the limiting process, but in this sum, there doesn't seem to be a $\Delta x$ term. I think the answer to this question would probably answer my another question,

[Laplace Transform: Continuous analogue of Power series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3189401/laplace-transform-continuous-analogue-of-power-series)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use choices of inner product that (a) indeed satisfy the axioms defining an inner product and (b) prove useful for our purposes. Under appropriate regularisation conditions, $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty f(n)g(n)$ (the sum implied to run over integers only, since you can't sum uncountably many terms) and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)g(x)dx$ are both inner products. But the latter is of greater interest when studying $\Bbb R\mapsto\Bbb R$ functions, since it runs over all values the arguments of $f,\,g$ can take.

In particular, (c) this integral is an inner product (proof is an exercise) and (d) you can't have an integral without the $dx$ part. What you can do, however, is replace $dx$ with the more general $dh(x)=h^\prime(x) dx$ to obtain $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)h^\prime(x)g(x) dx$, which is an inner product provided $h^\prime(x)>0$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$. (Similarly, $\sum_n f(n)j(n)g(n)$ is an inner product if $j(n)>0$ for $n\in\Bbb Z$).

So, "why $dx$?" really means "why take $h(x)=x$ for all $x$?" To which we can only answer, "use an $h$ that's convenient". For example, you'd use a very different $h$ if studying [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials), whereas in studying [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials) you'd take $h(x)=x$ *but* you'd restrict the integration range $[-1,\,1]$ (which still gives an inner product, just as in the discrete case one can restrict to summing over fewer $n$).

Comment: What different effect does adding a general $dh(x)$ has? is it like, instead of having double product, we make it a triple product and then get a $dx$ term? But the answer by Eric Miller is also intuitive, in what way does it differ form your answer? I mean How can we arrive at his answer with yours or vice versa

Comment: @AravindhVasu Oh no, it's not a "triple product". Just as a positive-definite matrix $M$ conformable with column vectors $u,\,v$ gives an inner product $(u^TMv)_{11}$, a suitable two-variable $M(x,\,y)$ makes $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}f(x)M(x,\,y)g(y)dxdy$ an even more general inner product, so e.g. we can take $M(x,\,y)=h^\prime (x)\delta(y)$.

Comment: Sorry, to be honest, I didn't get that comment at all, Can you explain it a bit more

Comment: @AravindhVasu You can think of the integral $fg$ as analogous to the usual dot product $u\cdot v$ on $\Bbb R^n$. What the $h^\prime$ factor does is replace that, in this analogy, with $u\cdot Mv$, with $M$ a diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are all positive. Those diagonal entries may look like a vector, but that's not the most helpful way to consider it.

Answer (score 1):

The $\Delta x$ term is just $1$, as the sum is over the integers. As you shorten the range, it is clear that a $\Delta x$ term is necessary.

Comment: Wow, that was simple :) Does this answer the linked question? I mean I get this, but then there seems to be an elaborate answer to the linked question, please go through the comments section, I really didn't understand his argument, does this relate to his argument?